# Quartz Scheduler: How to dynamically read a quartz property from Java via API?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

[Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/quick-start) is usually configured via `quartz.properties` on the classpath.

e.g.:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = BagginsScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool   
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=1
```

From within the same application that will run the Quartz jobs, **I'd like to read out the properties.**

Reading the scheduler name is easy:

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();  
String name = scheduler.getSchedulerName();
```

But how can I read the `threadPriority' property?

**The following does not work:**

```
scheduler.getContext().getString("org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority");
```

**UPDATED Solution**:
It seems that the property can't be read via Quartz API, you have to go via regular `Properties`:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(AnyClassUsedByJVM.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
String prio = prop.getProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority");
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add that property to your `quartz.properties`. For example:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=3
```

For more information, see [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool) and [configuration documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/)

**EDIT**: To read properties at runtime, you can use [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Here's a sample snippet of code you can use:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load("/tmp/quartz.properties"); // path to your properties file
System.out.println(p.getProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"); // prints 3
```

Comment: I know. The question is how to read the properties at runtime (e.g. to be displayed on an admin page)