# Liferay Quartz Scheduler cannot read properties from instance properties file

Tags: java, liferay, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing a Quartz Scheduler Job for a Liferay portlet and when trying to read some properties from portal-{webId}.properties, using `PropsUtil.get("property-key")`, it returns `null`. The properties configuration is correct, since I can get other properties from the same file in other portlets (not Quartz jobs). I know that all Quartz jobs are not bounded to specific instances, but can I somehow get the properties from the instance file or do I really need to put them in portal-ext.properties?

My setup is using DB sharding, if it makes any difference.
Also, I'm not interested in reading properties from other files, like suggested in [Quartz Scheduler: How to dynamically read a quartz property from Java via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103150/quartz-scheduler-how-to-dynamically-read-a-quartz-property-from-java-via-api).

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about moving it to the global portal-ext.properties...

Comment: I know that works, that's why I'm asking if there's another way.